# phpStorm/Xdebug can't show show child arrays of objects

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I'm trying to debug this code:

```
  public function removeBlankLines() {
    $this->qp->find('br');
  } // <-- break point is here
```

When I drill down into the $this object (using phpStorm) I can't see the child array I'm interested in.  It just displays "can not get property"  Screenshot:

[image: phpStorm debug pane screenshot]

I'm "listen for debug connections" feature.  I'm running the script from the command line.  PHP version:

```
[bwood@mbp ~]$ php -v
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Maybe related: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=996?

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15975 . I believe it's all because of how SplObjectStorage and alike (ArrayObject etc) are implemented **internally**. This should be an xdebug/php issue rather than PhpStorm's.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne.  So there's no fix/workaround?

Comment: Well .. see if adding it to the "Watches" panel will do any better (`$this->qp->matches->storage`). Otherwise comment/wait for response on xdebug issue tracker. P.S. You can also try latest 2.2.4 xdebug version .. but I believe is has no changes in this regard since your 2.2.3.

Comment: This has to do with visibility. Trying to use print_r() on the array I get: "Error: Cannot access protected property QueryPath\DOMQuery::$matches in
/Users/bwood/code/drupal/ucb-ist-drupal/migrate_uhs_policy/source_parser.inc, line 121"

Comment: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=686 -- see comments there -- it's all about how such classes are implemented internally...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=686

It's all about how such classes (`SplObjectStorage`, `ArrayObject` and alike) are implemented **internally**:

> this is because objects of the class SplObjectStorage are not user land PHP objects but special super duper internal ones. A similar situation will happen with many other internal PHP classes.

AFAIK nothing can be done on PhpStorm's side until xdebug will be able to "support" them.

---

**UPDATE:** The aforementioned xdebug ticket was resolved for **xdebug 2.3.3** quite some time ago (latest stable xdebug version is 2.4.1) and it should be possible to view such classes in debugger.

Comment: Can you confirm that it actually works with the new version of Xdebug? I just installed and enabled 2.4.1 on my vagrant machine, but I am still getting the aforementioned error when trying to view the storage property of an ArrayObject.

Comment: @Subsurf Please provide some simple code sample with some explanations/screenshot of how it looks on your side. I've just tested with code sample from the xdebug bug ticket using PhpStorm 2016.2.1 + PHP 5.6.26 (x86 nts) + xdebug 2.4.0 on Windows 7 and it showed me internals of `SplObjectStorage` object -- https://postimg.org/image/kwfwp52sh/

Comment: I'm still getting this error, even though I have Xdebug v2.4.0 and PhpStorm 2017.1.3.

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch Please create some simple reproducible code (ideally just one file); share it and show what and where it does not work. As you can see from my past screenshots it worked just fine with xdebug 2.4

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't happen in all situations, and it's happening in Drupal core.  I can't take too much time to chase this down right now.  Just thought I'd post that it still exists in rare circumstances.

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch In such case consider reporting it to [xdebug issue tracker](http://bugs.xdebug.org/) (when you will have a time and reproducible case -- e.g. if it happens in some standard module etc. where no own code is needed)

Answer (score 5):

- Upgrade your xdebug to version 2.3.3, it has fixed the problem
  http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=686#c3116
- If you are running vagrant make sure that you upgrade xdebug in
  vagrant virtual machine.
- Upgrade instructions can be obtained form http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

  If upgrading is not an option, you can dump the contents as a last
  resort.

  In evaluate expression you can try something like

  file_put_contents('dump.txt', var_export($requiredVariable,true));

Comment: This is a great workaround, `file_put_contents('dump.txt', var_export($requiredVariable,true));` thanks! The file will be created in the project root.

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade xdebug extension @john

Comment: reproducible on xdebug 2.9.2

Answer (score 1):

You will also get a **`! can not get property`** error if the property you are attempting to inspect is inherited from a parent class and not visible from your current scope.

## Example:

xDebug will annotate the relevant property like such:

```
$childClass = {path\to\child\Child}
    *path\to\class\Parent*property = {path\to\property\Property}
```

Where:

- `Parent` is the base class
- `Child` is the extending class
- `property` is the inherited property, defined on Parent

Note the asterisk `*` which identify this case and denote '*not visible from current scope*'.

## Solution:

The quick solution to enable debugging is to set the parent's property's visibility to `public`.

ie

```
class Parent {
    public $property;  // instead of private or protected
}

class Child extends Parent{
    // You can now inspect parent::$property for instances of Child 
}
```

Remember to set the property visibility back to the correct value when finished testing.

Comment: I have this problem when extending an SplFileObject. I guess there is no way of seeing the contents of the object in that case?

Answer (score 0):

> Linux **LDME2**
>   php**5.6.30-0+deb8u1**
>   xdebug v**2.5.3**

I tryed this recept.

```
php -i | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Put to, and followed the instructions

```
https://xdebug.org/wizard.php
```

I got this result (**can not get property**)

> sha256sum ~/xdebug-from-src/xdebug-2.5.3/modules/xdebug.so
>       afbb70941387ff1e191433d2a09ff42a393caac773194c0e9004b844a0f3d73b

I finded fix for this problem. Instead build from source, need install from pecl

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

> sha256sum /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so 
>   b82f2a4ab101323d3600a79223143e2eefe941d404c88af2bd7434fd47caaf13

```
php -v
```

> PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2017 08:50:21)  Copyright (c)
>   1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.5.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans